# Creating an Esri multipatch object in ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, multipatch

Can you give me more detailed information about creating a multipatch object? When we import a 3D data format to ArcScene how does it convert it to multipatch? How does it triangulate a polygon surface to triangles? Which algorithm or rule does it use to create patches such as triangle strip, triangle fun and ring from polygon surface? How does the software decide creation of triange strip of fan for a surface? As you can see in the attaching file

[image: Multipatch parts]

Comment: There are many questions here, most of which can only be answered by "It depends", or "Because that's how the programmer coded it". Making your own multipatch objects is simple, but very tedious,  since you have to do it ***right*** to get a display.  Please **edit** your question to focus on a single aspect of multipatch creation, and if coding-specific, include your own code with detailed information on the development environment.